# ¿Cómo puedo agregar lineas de referencia en ggplot2 y ajustar la escala?

Tags: r, rstudio, ggplot2

Estoy replicando esta gráfica en r, usando la paqueteria ggplot2, sin embargo, no se como poner las lineas rojas de referencia, no se si tengo que hacer un vector nuevo para las tres lineas o se pueden agregar en automático con algún comando.

Aparte, abusando de su confianza, no se muy bien aún como mover la escala de los ejes, es decir, recortar ceros o agregar las comas para que salgan mas presentables las gráficas.

De antemano muchas gracias, agradezco mucho su atención, y espero que la respuesta sirva a alguien mas en un futuro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La diagonal parece la recta de regresión, ¿es efectivamente así?¿Podrías agregar lo que llevas hecho hasta ahora y alguna muestra de los datos?

Comment: Hola Patricio. Si, bueno, estoy tratando de replicarla, pero hasta ahorita he tenido problemas, primero por el mapeo de los datos, no se como mapear la gráfica de dispersión de dos entradas y no se como ajustar tampoco los ejes para que los datos aparezcan acomodados de esa forma, para posteriormente agregar las etiquetas a los puntos. La gráfica de la foto esta hecha en STATA, y si, la diagonal es la recta regresora de un año contra ese mismo año para que de 1. En cuanto a los datos son el PIBE estatal de cada uno de la republica. Muchas gracias Patricio, también me ayudaste la vez pasada

Comment: Se me olvido comentar que en el data frame, tengo un vector con el nombre del estado y en otro vector tengo los valores para el estado en el año 2003 y en otro vector tengo los valores para el estado en el año 2016.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Los comandos `geom_vline()` `geom_hline()` y `geom_abline()` pueden ayudarte.

Si tienes una tabla:

```
DF=data.frame("X"=rnorm(n=10, mean=4, sd=2), "Y"=rnorm(n=10, mean=10, sd=2))
```

Puedes agregar lineas de referencia como sigue:

```
ggplot(data=DF, aes(x=X, y=Y)) + geom_point() +
  geom_vline(xintercept=3) + #Linea Vertical cuando x es igual a 3
  geom_hline(yintercept=11) + #Linea horizontal cuando y es igual a 11
  geom_abline(intercept=9, slope=0.5) #Linea diagonal indicando el intercepto y la pendiente
```

El código de arriba genera el siguiente gráfico:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En general, para `geom_abline()`, los datos saldrán de una regresión lineal, como te lo han dicho en los comentarios.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Cris, de verdad me ayudo bastante. En seguida voy a tratar de replicarlos. Te agradezco tu tiempo.

Answer (score 1):

Voy a partir de estos datos que obtuve de la página del INEGI, aunque seguramente no son los indicados, pero sirven a modo de ejemplo:

```
df <- structure(list(estado = c("Aguascalientes", "Baja California", 
                                "Baja California Sur", "Campeche", "Coahuila de Zaragoza", "Colima", 
                                "Chiapas", "Chihuahua", "Ciudad de México", "Durango", "Guanajuato", 
                                "Guerrero", "Hidalgo", "Jalisco", "México", "Michoacán de Ocampo", 
                                "Morelos", "Nayarit", "Nuevo León", "Oaxaca", "Puebla", "Querétaro", 
                                "Quintana Roo", "San Luis Potosí", "Sinaloa", "Sonora", "Tabasco", 
                                "Tamaulipas", "Tlaxcala", "Veracruz de Ignacio de la Llave", 
                                "Yucatán", "Zacatecas"), Y2003 = c(121197.634, 399514.624, 76047.593, 
                                                                   1047511.322, 436573.518, 67732.93, 248123.227, 360426.663, 2132929.372, 
                                                                   152922.727, 438354.387, 182713.981, 179553.378, 794957.322, 1048403.59, 
                                                                   294468.306, 158055.834, 76105.196, 803888.528, 202963.936, 395907.258, 
                                                                   212106.713, 144233.02, 224280.267, 268247.066, 365533.727, 374891.404, 
                                                                   391574.439, 83254.186, 613590.201, 161636.497, 101406.31), Y2016 = c(216329.062, 
                                                                                                                                        528019.895, 134229.433, 601213.978, 583337.17, 101187.003, 290720.226, 
                                                                                                                                        540519.412, 2961088.314, 202334.385, 689459.704, 237009.518, 
                                                                                                                                        264151.579, 1161974.794, 1482034.153, 408268.071, 192332.162, 
                                                                                                                                        119713.978, 1238927.405, 256500.787, 553207.194, 386014.465, 
                                                                                                                                        263393.367, 342645.563, 381751.628, 567728.069, 529964.246, 490654.467, 
                                                                                                                                        97276.984, 803433.088, 242440.579, 156594.847)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                       -32L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Un gráfico básico tipo *scatterplot* podría ser así:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=Y2003, y=Y2016)) +
    labs(title = "PIBE Estatal Mexico 2003 - 2016",
         x = "Año 2003",
         y = "Año 2016",
         caption = "Fuente: elaboración popia con datos del INEGI") +
    geom_point(col="blue") +
    geom_text(aes(label=estado))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El principal problema de este gráfico, sin duda, es la ciudad de México cuyos valores se "escapan" mucho del resto, provocando una acumulación de puntos para el resto de los estados, el otro problema es que las etiquetas de los puntos no se ubican del todo bien.

Para resolver la acumulación de puntos, hay dos trucos que puedes usar: (1) modificar las escalas `x` e `y` por una escala logarítmica, lo cual hará que los puntos se ajusten mejor, el otro, es ajustar el `alpha` o  transparencia, lo que permite distinguir aquellos casos en que los puntos se solapan. Para (2) el problema de las etiquetas, es recomendable usar el paquete `ggrepel`, te ofrece la gráfica `geom_text_repel` que remplaza el `geom_text` por un texto mucho mejor ubicado.

Por otro lado, tienes otras dudas:

- Como dibujar la línea de regresión y las horizontales y verticales dados un `x` y un `y`. Para la línea de regresión, podemos claro, calcular la pendiente ejecutando un modelo lineal o directamente usar `geom_smooth()`. Las otras lineas las dibujaremos con `geom_hline()` y  `geom_vline()`
- En cuanto al formato de los números en las etiquetas de los ejes, podemos definir la función `scales::comma` para formatearlos de forma más legible

Ejemplo:

```
library(ggrepel)
ggplot(df, aes(x=Y2003, y=Y2016)) +
    labs(title = "PIBE Estatal Mexico 2003 - 2016",
         x = "Año 2003",
         y = "Año 2016",
         caption = "Fuente: elaboración popia con datos del INEGI") +
    geom_point(col="blue", size = 3, alpha=0.5) + 
    geom_smooth(method = "lm", color="red", se = FALSE) +
    geom_text_repel(aes(label=estado), label.padding=.1, seed=1234, fill = NA, alpha=0.7, size = 3) +    geom_hline(aes(yintercept=2000000), color="red") +
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept=2000000), color="red") +
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept=2000000), color="red") +
    scale_x_log10(labels = scales::comma) +
    scale_y_log10(labels = scales::comma)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agregamos la leyenda para la línea de tendencia y configuramos algo más el tema:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Y2003, y=Y2016)) +
    labs(title = "PIBE Estatal Mexico 2003 - 2016",
         x = "Año 2003",
         y = "Año 2016",
         caption = "Fuente: elaboración popia con datos del INEGI") +
    geom_point(col="blue", size = 3, alpha=0.5) + 
    scale_x_log10(labels = scales::comma) +
    scale_y_log10(labels = scales::comma) +
    geom_smooth(aes(color = 'Tendencia'), method = "lm", se = FALSE, show.legend = TRUE) +
    geom_text_repel(aes(label=estado), label.padding=.1, seed=1234, fill = NA, alpha=0.7, size = 3) +    geom_hline(aes(yintercept=2000000), color="red") +
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept=2000000), color="red") +
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept=2000000), color="red") +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.box = "horizontal", legend.title=element_blank())
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Patricio, nuevamente me ayudas muchísimo, te agradezco enormemente tu ayuda. Y de verdad espero llegar a ser tan bueno como tu algún día. Muchas muchas gracias.

Comment: Patricio, ya por ultimo y abusando de su confianza, ¿como podría yo, añadir una caja de leyendas dónde esten explicadas el significado de las lineas rojas en la gráfica?

Comment: @CarlosAlbertoFlores, verifica mi última edición. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio